# socket.io makes 404 requests

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I get 404 on urls like this: `http://localhost.dev/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1411749802784-54`

**SOCKET IO VERSION:** 1.x

**APP.JS**

```
    var express = require("express"),
    app     = express(),
    server  = require('http').createServer(app),
    io      = require('socket.io').listen(server),

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    console.log('started');
});

//Receive message
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('send message',function(data){
        //Send message out
        io.sockets.emit('new message',data);
    });
});
```

So I have my website which is running on `port 80` and nodejs on port `8080` and I include socket.io js file like this: `<script src="http://localhost.dev:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` and I can open the `socket.io.js` file in a new tab, but I guess this has something to do with the new version, I am just getting started with node.

//LE

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Socket.io
    var socket = io.connect();
    //Form
    var $messageForm      = $('#chatForm');
    var $messageFormInput = $messageForm.find('#messageText');
    var $chat             = $('.chat');

    //Bind submit form
    $messageForm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('send message',$messageFormInput.val());
        //Clear input
        $messageFormInput.val('');
    });

    //Receive message
    socket.on('new message',function(data){
        $chat.append(data);
    });









});
```

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: If you're getting 404 errors in your console on `http://localhost.dev/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1411749802784-54` then you may not be adding the script from the 8080 port correctly in your page. The fact that the url isn't `http://localhost.dev:8080/socket.io/` is a pretty good indicator that something funky is going on with the url, not node/socket.io

Comment: As you can see somehow it doesn make the request on port `:8080` if you look at the first 404 url

Comment: Have you double checked your HTML source (by viewing source or inspecting with developer console tools) to make sure that the script tag the browser is reading does in fact have the 8080 on it? If the script tag says 8080, the request should be for 8080. Either that or you've got some plugin in your browser causing it to ignore the port. The browser isn't going to ignore the 8080 port on a url all by itself.

Comment: Yes I did check with devtools and view source

Comment: Where's your `io.connect()` code?  What does that look like?

Comment: Ah I just noticed the url wasn't the actual socket.io library :X what @jfriend00 is asking for is the missing piece. When you connect: `var socket = io('http://localhost');` does that url have the 8080 in it? Because if not, that's likely the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost.dev:8080');
```

Comment: That's the issue. The webpage itself is loading over 80 (default) but the socket.io is listening over 8080. So the page wants to request the urls off 80, but it needs to use 8080

Comment: It doesn't work...I still get 404, @jfriend00 the node and apache server are on different ports

Comment: @Uffo - if they are on different ports, then you will have to specify the port when you connect from the client.  `io.connect()` by itself connects to the port that the web page was loaded from.  It does not know where the websocket server is if it's not on the same host and port as the web page was loaded from.

Comment: They work now, I forgot the http: I was using // in `io.connect`